# django search form with pagination

Tags: django, django-filter

How to add django_filters search form as part of modeladmin changelist page itself. The user should be able to search from the various model attributes and the query should generate the necessary search result. Using django 1.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  f = ModelFilter(request.GET, queryset=Model.objects.all())
    paginator = Paginator(f.qs,100)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        modelobjects = paginator.page(page)
```

Pass the values as context:

```
ctx = RequestContext(request, {
            'filter':f,
            'modelobjects': modelobjects,
            })
```

in template.py:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <table border="1">
  <tr>
  <th>Sr.No.</th>
  <th>Number </th>
 </tr>
    {% for line in modelobjects %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
       ..........
```

Follow the document for pagination here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view that's all!